# Get system date and time as string when a button is clicked - VC++ Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

I am working on a windows forms application and using c++, not c#. I have a button in my form. This button, when clicked, must get system date and time and assign the values to strings *Year*, *Month*, *Day*, *Hour*, *Minute* seperately. How can I achieve this? What should I write in the button's click event handler?

Note: I am totally newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean:

```
String^ Year = System::DateTime::Now.Year.ToString();
String^ Month = System::DateTime::Now.Month.ToString();
String^ Day = System::DateTime::Now.Day.ToString();
String^ Hour = System::DateTime::Now.Hour.ToString();
String^ Minute = System::DateTime::Now.Minute.ToString();
```

The Hour value is represented in the 24-hour system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.DateTime.Now property. It has everything you want.